# Using nested loops and fin correctly

Tags: c++

I have a question about using fin and loops correctly in C++. I have a file I read from that has 78 lines of data consisting of a ski resort name, its elevation, and then 12 numbers that are the monthly precipitation. The program is supposed to read from that file then output to a different file the name, elevation, and the average annual precipitation. For some reason I can't get the average to work right. I have to have one loop run for each of the 78 lines, then a nested loop run to process each of the 12 months.

I also have to use a cin.ignore that I don't know where to put.

Code:

```
int main() {

ifstream fin("../Debug/monthlyPrecipitation.txt");

if (fin.fail())
{
    cout << "Error opening file." << endl;
}

ofstream fout;
fout.open("../Debug/annualPrecipitation.txt", ios::app);

int elevation;
const int MONTHSPERYEAR = 12;
double average, precipTotal, precip;
string stationName;

fout << "Annual Precipitation Report" << endl;
fout << endl;
fout << "Weather Station" << setw(18) << "Elevation" << setw(12) << "Precipitation" << endl << endl;

for (int counter = 1; counter <= 78; ++counter)
{
    getline(fin, stationName, '\t');
    fin >> elevation;

    for (int counter = 1; counter <= 12; ++counter)
        {
            fin >> precip;
            precipTotal = precipTotal + precip; //the issue is here
        }

        average = precipTotal / MONTHSPERYEAR;

        fout << stationName << setw(22) << elevation << setw(12) << average << endl;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `fin` is just a variable name you chose. It's not useful in the title or in the body of the question

Answer (score 1):

Along with contaminating precipTotal, It looks like you're forgetting to turn the line into a stringstream. I'm assuming that a line in your file looks like:

Resort_Name elevation precip1 precip2 ... precip12

if you get that line, then you're grabbing all the precips along with it, and then when you fin in the inner loop, you're reading in the next line. What you need to do is get that line, and turn it into a stringstream. Then, read in the resort name into a different string, the elevation into an int, and then calculate the average without contaminating the total.

Answer (score 0):

You're not clearing precipTotal before the inner loop, thus contaminating the average of a given station with the results of the previous ones.

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize all the POD variables such as `elevation`, `average`, `precipTotal`, and `precip`.
However, only `precipTotal` has an issue because the others have new value in the loop.